# A characterization of differentiability of a convex function

Tags: analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

Let $\phi : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a convex function. For all point $x\in \mathbb R^n$, define the subdifferential as

$$\partial \phi(x) = \{ y\in \mathbb R^n | \ \phi(z) \geq \phi(x) + y\cdot (z-x)\ \ \forall z\in \mathbb R^n\}$$

If $\phi$ is differentiable at $x$, then $\partial \phi(x)$ contains one point, which is the gradient $\nabla \phi(x)$. Is the converse true? That is, if $\partial \phi(x) = \{y_0\}$, is it true that $\phi$ is differentiable at $x$ and $\nabla \phi(x) = y_0$? Thanks in advance for any comment and reference.

Comment: Is true: http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/notes/subgradients_notes.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment, this is true. A standard reference: Theorem 25.1 on page 242 of

> Rockafellar, R. Tyrrell, *Convex analysis*. Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1970.

By the way, the book has $2885+388$ MathSciNet citations as of now (388 coming from its 1997 preprint).